# simple C code to either read a file or stdin

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Absolutely new to C. I am trying to write a program to either read integers contained in a file (passed as arg) or from `stdin`. First number read is supposed to indicate the array size.
I have something but it throws segmentation fault. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FILE *f;
    int n, numbers[n], firstNum;

    if (argc != 0)
    {

        f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        fscanf(f, "%d", & firstNum);

        int numbersArray[firstNum];

        for (int i = 0; i < firstNum; i++)
        {
            fscanf(f, "%d", &numbersArray[i]);
        }

        for (int i = firstNum; 0 <= i; i--)
        {
            printf("Numbers: %d\n\n", numbersArray[i]);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
    else
        scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fscanf(stdin, "%d", &numbers[i]);
        printf("%d\n", i, numbers[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int n, numbers[n];` That is incorrect code. `n` is uninitialised and using it in the second statement results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: n is not initialized, always initialize your variables to a value when doing C.

Comment: When asking for debugging help, always tell us what line your faulting on.  Don't make us guess.

Comment: As a beginner (and even as a pro) you should always check the return value of all functions. In this case `fopen` and `fscanf`.

Comment: The second loop: `int i = firstNum` should be `int i = firstNum-1`

Comment: `if (argc != 0)` That's always going to be true because `argv` includes the executable name in the first entry. So `argc` is always at least `1` and hence the `else` block never runs.

Comment: thanks for the above, GDB says SIGSEGV , responsible function  is  fscanf

Answer (score 0):

First off always initialize your variables like kaylum and myself mentioned in the comments.
Unlike some other programming languages C doesn't initialize your variables for you.
Now for the question you posted, you got the idea mostly correct but there are things that i suggest you change:

```
int n, numbers[n], firstNum;
```

to

```
int n = 0, numbers[1000], firstNum = 0;
```

If you're not happy with that you could move the numbers[n] lower when n is initialized but i wouldn't advise that.
Instead of that, since you're learning C have a look at dynamically allocated arrays using pointers.
Some links to help you understand pointers:

https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

Next have a look at your `fopen`  it has a return value that tells you if it succeeded to open the file you requested.

So you can add:

```
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("File Not Found!");
        return -1;
    }
```

Modify the condition to suite the way you want to handle that error.

When you're reading the file the user specifies the size of the array you're reading but you should consider the fact that the file may not contain the exact amount of elements.
The function that you are using `fscanf` has a way to tell you that and that's it's return value.
It will return `EOF` which is a special value that translates to End Of File.

Consider modifying your fscanf to this:

```
    if (fscanf(f, "%d", &firstNum) == EOF)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
    }
```

Or if you're in a for loop put `break`

The last thing is that you don't have to explicitly use `fscanf` for `stdin`, the user has specified that he will input it through `stdin` so you can just as well use `scanf`.
Hope this helps and good luck with your future C endeavors.